# How to reverse an arbitrary array in go?

Tags: arrays, sorting, go

Of course, one can always write a for loop. But code sharing is usually always good. So is there a way to write a method that sorts *any* array? Also, performance, so I'm guessing that rules out reflection.

`sort.Reverse` doesn't seem to work. The following will not compile:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type A struct {
    X int
}

func main() {
x := make([]A, 0)
x = append(x, A{1})
x = append(x, A{2})
sort.Reverse(sort.IntSlice(x))
fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Comment: If something won't compile or run, include any errors generated in your question.

Comment: "But code sharing is always good." From wrong assumptions follows arbitrary falsehood.

Comment: OK @volker, maybe not always but in this context yes! I'd hate to work on code where I'm copy/pasting reverse loops all over the place (in fact, that's what prompted this question). DRY anyone?

Answer (score 1):

`[]A` is not an int slice, it's a slice of structs and you must implement a `sort.Interface` to describe how to sort it.

Here's a working example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type A struct {
    X int
}

type ByX []A

func (a ByX) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a ByX) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a ByX) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i].X < a[j].X }

func main() {
    x := make([]A, 0)
    x = append(x, A{1})
    x = append(x, A{2})
    sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(ByX(x)))
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

[Try it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uMncReY6NvQ).

Alternatively, you can call `sort.Slice` and provide it with only the `Less` function:

```
sort.Slice(x, func(i, j int) bool { return x[i].X > x[j].X })
```

You should notice that the less function is different. Since we want to sort in reverse and the shorthand `sort.Slice` isn't compatible with `sort.Reverse`, we had to modify the less function to return the opposite (`>` instead of `<`).

Comment: You don't have to use the interface any more. You can just use [sort.Slice](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice).

Comment: Ah sort.Reverse expects an ordering. How does this compare to a `for` loop? It's a shame a built-in "array" interface doesn't exist, so that you could just write a generic for loop.

Comment: @UAvalos This isn't unique to Go. When you want to sort an array of objects, you must specify the ordering since the sort function can't tell by which field or fields you want to sort. Even in python you must say: `people.sort(lambda person: person.name)` which isn't very far from Go's `sort.Slice` shorthand.

Comment: Even in python? Not true in Javascript. Not true in Java. You've misunderstood the comments if you think you must specify a sort function... (Reverse literally means the array in reverse, no sort ordering required)